# How to select first occurence in each div?

Tags: jquery

My structure looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3"> <!-- select -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3"> <!-- select -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3"> <!-- select -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In container I need to select each first rows first `col-lg-3`. Is it possible to do with `jQuery` selectors or I should loop each row?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[parent > child](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)** selector:

```
$('#container > .row > .col-lg-3')
```